# VIA Rail Services offered in Business vs Business Plus class

Tags: trains, canada

What is the difference between VIA Rail's Business and Business plus classes?
VIA Rail is now offering to classes in business class, Business and Business Plus.
I cannot find anywhere on the VIA website a description of the difference between the services being offered.

Answer (score 2):

The [fare comparison page at Via Rail](http://www.viarail.ca/en/fares-and-packages/fare-comparison) has the information you need. There is no difference in the onboard experience (nor the at-station experience such as using the lounge) at all. The only difference is in the flexibility of the fare - change fees and cancellation fees.

You can see the same pattern with Economy and Economy Plus - same onboard experience, less change fees etc for the Plus.